# MVC passing a list to view object reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following view model structure:

```
public class ClubViewModel
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public IList<CalendarEntryViewModel> MeetingDays { get; set; }          
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}

 public class CalendarEntryViewModel
{
    public Days Day { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }        
}
```

Im trying to add a **CREATE** view to my project which will accommodate the list and give me an option for Monday - Sunday.

I have added the following to my Create view:

```
@for (int meetingDay = 0; meetingDay < Model.MeetingDays.Count; meetingDay++)
{
    @* Get the current day of week *@
    var dayOfWeek = Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), meetingDay);

    <label>@dayOfWeek Start</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.MeetingDays[meetingDay].From)
    <label>@dayOfWeek Finish</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.MeetingDays[meetingDay].To)
}
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateNew()
{

    ClubViewModel viewModel = new ClubViewModel();
```

viewModel.MeetingDays = new List();

```
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Monday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Tuesday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Wednesday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Thursday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Friday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Saturday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Sunday });

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Im trying to pass to my view one day for each day of the week so that the user will be able to provide a to/from for each day but im getting:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create instance of list `MeetingDays` and after that add items to list:

```
public ActionResult CreateNew()
{

    ClubViewModel viewModel = new ClubViewModel();

    viewModel.MeetingDays = new List<CalendarEntryViewModel>();

    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Monday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Tuesday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Wednesday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Thursday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Friday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Saturday });
    viewModel.MeetingDays.Add(new CalendarEntryViewModel { Day = Days.Sunday });

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Just realised this as you answered, sometimes it takes writing out your question to have a lightbulb moment, thanks!